# can join 1 table with 1 table more than 1 time in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have an issues with NHibernate when join 1 table with 1 table more than 1 time.
I use ICriteria.
I have 2 tables. let's see:

tblEmployees:

```
EmployeeID (PK)
Gender (will join with table tblCommons) (this is Key data in tblCommons)
Status (will join with table tblCommons) (this is Key data in tblCommons)
```

note: tblEmployees doesn't has any PK of tblCommons.

tblCommons:

```
ID (PK)
Code (will use to specific Gender data and Status data) (ex: 1 is Gender, 2 is Status)
Key
Value
```

this is data in tblEmployees:

```
EmployeeID                 Gender                  Status 
  1                          1                        1
  2                          1                        2
  3                          2                        1
```

and this is data in tblCommons

```
ID                  Code                  Key                   Value
1                     1                     1                   Male
2                     1                     2                   Female
3                     2                     1                   Active
4                     2                     2                   Inactive
```

In Employees.hbm.xml file

```
<class name="Demo.Employees, Demo" table="tblEmployees">
    <id name="EmployeeID" column="EmployeeID" type="String">
    </id>
    <many-to-one class="Demo.Commons, Demo" name="Gender" column="Gender" />
    <many-to-one class="Demo.Commons, Demo" name="Status" column="Status" />
</class>
```

In Employees class

```
namespace Demo
{
    public class Employees
    {
        public Employees(){}
        public virtual string EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public virtual Commons Gender{ get; set; }
        public virtual Commons Status{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

In Commons.hbm.xml

```
<class name="Demo.Commons, Demo" table="tblCommons">
    <id name="Key" column="Key" type="String">
    </id>
    <property name="Code" column="Code" type="String" />
    <property name="Value" column="Value" type="String" />
    <set name="Genders" table="tblEmployees" generic="true" inverse="true">
      <key column="Gender" />
      <one-to-many class="Demo.Employees, Demo"/>
    </set>
    <set name="Status" table="tblEmployees" generic="true" inverse="true">
      <key column="Status" />
      <one-to-many class="Demo.Employees, Demo"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

note: in xml, I set "id" is "Key", because I see in NHibernate, "id" is a data that will be join with another tables. Here, in tblEmployees, Gender and Status in tblEmployees is "Key" data in tblCommons. so, I set "id" in xml is "Key"

In Commons class

```
namespace Demo
{
    public class Commons
    {
        public Commons(){}
        public virtual string Key { get; set; }
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }
        public virtual string Value { get; set; }
        public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Employees> Genders { get; set; }
        public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Employees> Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

note: I don't set "ID" in tblCommons in xml file and Commons Class, because I don't use "ID" data in my project

this is code that I use to get Employees Data

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Employees));
criteria.CreateCriteria("Gender", "Gender", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Gender.Code", "1"));
criteria.CreateCriteria("Status", "Status", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status.Code", "2"));
IList<Employees> list = new List<Employees>();
list = criteria.List<Employees>();
```

I have a problem here:

in "list", "Gender" in Employees Object has data of "Status"
if I change like this: CreateCriteria "Status" first and then, CreateCriteria "Gender" , "Status" has data of "Gender".

I don't know why. I just using NHibernate about 1 month. please help me why I have that issues. thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the Key column as the ID property in Commons object. 
ID property should be unique and detached from any "meaningful" data.
You should add ID property to your Commons class, and turn Key to a regular property.
Change your mapping, pay attention to the "set" mappings -

```
    <class name="Demo.Commons, Demo" table="tblCommons">
       <id name="ID" column="ID" type="String">
          <generator class="identity"/>
       </id>
       <property name="Key" column="Key" type="String" />
       <property name="Code" column="Code" type="String" />
       <property name="Value" column="Value" type="String" />
       <set name="Genders" table="tblEmployees" generic="true" inverse="true">
         <key column="Key" property-ref="Gender" />
         <one-to-many class="Demo.Employees, Demo"/>
       </set>
       <set name="Status" table="tblEmployees" generic="true" inverse="true">
          <key column="Key" property-ref="Status" />
          <one-to-many class="Demo.Employees, Demo"/>
       </set>
  </class>



  <class name="Demo.Employees, Demo" table="tblEmployees">
      <id name="EmployeeID" column="EmployeeID" type="String">
      </id>
      <many-to-one class="Demo.Commons, Demo" name="Gender" column="Gender" property-ref="Key"/>
      <many-to-one class="Demo.Commons, Demo" name="Status" column="Status" property-ref="Key"/>
  </class>
```